# how to send HTML data using SOAP web service

Tags: java, html, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP web service and I am sending HTML(as String) over SOAP method. Problem is How can i send this HTML with image files. What is the best practice? I have found that I can embed this image files as Base64 to HTML file but It is a little painful for all image files. Is there any idea?

Comment: @user1831003 No it is about ios. Doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Base64 will result in about 33% increase in size, it's ok for small sized file.